# UICollectionView reorder unmovable cell issue

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I am making a UICollectionView with iOS 9's cool reorder feature. I can make a cell unmovable by returning No in the datasource's function `- (BOOL)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView canMoveItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` for that index path.

However, I found the cell is able to be replaced with movable items, which is not expected.

For example,

[We cannot move the 3rd item (screenshot).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V34A0.png)

[But it is able to be the destination index path for other cell to move to(screenshot).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zk6z6.png)

any good ideas for the 3rd cell to be really fixed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assume item at indexpath = {x,y} cannot be moved. Try use following delegate method.

```
collectionView(_:targetIndexPathForMoveFromItemAtIndexPath:toProposedIndexPath:)
```

If the proposed index path is equal to `{x,y}` then you provide desired index path for the item. Ex `{x+1,y}`

From the docs:

> During the interactive moving of an item, the collection view calls
>   this method to see if you want to provide a different index path than
>   the proposed path. You might use this method to prevent the user from
>   dropping the item in an invalid location. For example, you might
>   prevent the user from dropping the item in a specific section.